# Android debug error 'Unable to identify the apk for variant armv7-debug'

Tags: android, cordova, simulator, genymotion

When trying to debug my Cordova Android app to a Genymotion simulator, I get the following error:

'Unable to identify the apk for variant armv7-debug'

I can debug on a real device just fine - though I want to target specific Android versions with the simulator. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is Genymotion uses x86 instead of arm architecture, and doesn't seem to come with libhoudini (arm to x86 translator) pre-installed.

You have two options:

1. install the native arm translation, which I have never had much luck with, will occasionally crash my devices with no warning, and is the #1 cause of crashes in my app in production - http://mir.cr/0ZIO8PME

OR

2. Build a native x86 binary of your app. Assuming you are using the most recent Cordova 4.0, this is default with gradle, and you will be able to find an x86 build already done along side the arm build. According to the Cordova release notes, you can manually trigger gradle if it isn't already enabled with:

   cordova build android -- --gradle

Best of luck!